# Почему мой код регистрации количества скачиваний не работает?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Я написал вот такой код для регистраций количества скачиваний в посте:

```
 <a href="images/xxx.jpg" download onclick="function_download_js()" class="clickme">Click Me</a>
```

js.code

```
function function_download_js() {
        jQuery('document').ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ' <?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/content_theme/single/programs/download/download_withdraw.php ',
                    success: function(data) {
                    $("body").append($(data));
                    } }); }); }
```

файл download_withdraw.php

```
$postID = get_the_ID() ;
$number_download = get_post_meta($postID, 'download_registration', true);
$number_download++;
update_post_meta($postID, 'download_registration', $number_download);
```

Но проблема в том, что он не видит хуки WordPress.

Есть ли у кого идеи, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Не хуки он не видит, а функции WordPress. Вы вызываете ваш файл `download_withdraw.php` "в лоб" из jQuery. В нём просто ваш код, и более ничего. Там нет инициализации ядра WordPress, функции `get_the_ID()`, `get_post_meta()`, `update_post_meta()` не определены, и ваш код завершается с кодом 500.

Почитайте [документацию на русском](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html) о том, как правильно создавать ajax-запросы в WordPress.

И даже после того, как вы всё сделаете по этой документации, приведённый код не будет работать, потому что функция `get_the_ID()` работает только внутри главного цикла WordPress. А никакого цикла в обработчике ajax-запроса нет. Вам надо как-то в jQuery определять id текущей страницы (например, по классу в body, стандартные темы присваивают body класс типа postid-11). А вычисленный внутри jQuery id отправлять как параметр ajax-запроса, чтобы использовать его в вашем обработчике `download_withdraw.php`.